# USB Printer not showing up on `control printers`, but showing up on `devmgmt.msc`

Tags: windows-7, usb, printing, printer

I have a USB printer (D110a) that was installed using the HP official driver pack previously, and worked fine. It has no operating failure.

When I connect it to the Windows 7 PC it always worked with, I can hear the sound of a new USB device being recognized, and can see it correctly listed on `devmgmt.msc`.

But `control printers` remains blank, and I CAN print using that printer, through the print dialog called by every program.

What could be preventing me from seeing it on `control printers`? It is annoying and I would like to be able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this (perhaps you might see it as a workaround) is as follows:

Uninstall (Control Panel, Programs and Features) all D110a printer apps. There may be more than one. Unplug the printer. Restart the computer.

Plug in the Printer.  Open Devices and Printers and Select Add a Printer. Select the D110a and let Windows add the printer.

The printer should now appear in Devices and Printers and also it should print (do a test page).

This method of letting Windows add printers normally works very well.

You can also try reinstalling the Printer Driver.  Uninstall completely as I noted above. Restart, Now reinstall the D110a.

The Windows drivers (Microsoft Catalogue) are supplied by the printer manufacturer anyway.

Comment: So it would be a trade-off between having the HP official software pack, and having the printer to appear on `control printers`? Or could I reinstall the official software pack after the procedures you detailed?

Comment: You can try reinstalling the printer (uninstall, restart and install again), or try what I suggested.

Comment: I added the reinstall step to my answer.  The Windows drivers are supplied by the Manufactuer.